# Replacing a specific string from a directory of files using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to replace a list of filenames inside a directory. For example

```
cd /home/towers
ls

c3_slo_live_ox_dns_m2m_pcg.yaml
c3_slo_live_ox_dns_service_pcg_physnet4.yaml
c3_slo_live_ox_dns_service_pcg_physnet2.yaml

to

cd /home/towers
ls

c3_dsd_live_ox_dns_m2m_pcg.yaml
c3_dsd_live_ox_dns_service_pcg_physnet4.yaml
c3_dsd_live_ox_dns_service_pcg_physnet2.yaml

Which is the best way? can we use sed? Any example that I should try?
```

Comment: what do you mean by "reaplace a list" in context of files in directory?

Comment: `for f in * ; do mv "$f" "${f/slo/dsd}" ; done` -- bash parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you what you wanted is to rename the files according a replacement pattern you could try something like this:

```
for file in *;do mv $file $(echo $file|sed 's/_slo_/_dsd_/'); done
```

- This will loop through every file in your current directory and replace the _slo_ string with _dsd_

I recommend you double check that this pattern isn't used unintentionally in other parts of your filenames before you commit to it.

Comment: Probably try https://shellcheck.net/ on this before trying to use it; it contains several beginner mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
rename 's/_slo_/_dsd_/' *
```

This uses the perl rename program.

Comment: Not working, rename: not enough arguments

Comment: @Siddharth if you summon the manual i.e. `man rename` do you get author `Larry Wall` if not this is not the perl version of rename.